# Too much recursion on setInterval and Fades

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have a screensaver I adapted from a background. However, the only issue is the screensaver only works once, or twice, before throughing the error: `Too much recursion` I read this is from 'bubbling' up of triggers but I'm not sure how to prevent it. I've reworked the code a few times now.

**Wait ten seconds for screensaver to start** move mouse to stop it, error starts there usually.

**Error**

```
too much recursion jquery.min.js:2
```

http://codepen.io/WAS/pen/fuHLn

```
var i = 0,
    screensaver = $('#screensaver'),
    startTime = 100,
    isOff = true;

function countit () {
  if ( i >= startTime && isOff == true ) {
    screensaver.fadeIn('slow', function() {
      isOff = false;
    });
  }
  screensaver.bind('mousemove', function(e){
     i=0;
     screensaver.fadeOut('fast');
  });
  i++;
}

$(window).ready(function(){

  var screensaver = setInterval(countit, 100);

});
```

Comment: Your fiddle says Forums and stuff here....

Comment: Yeah, you need to wait 10 seconds like the code shows. Or your browser does not support shaders.

Comment: after 10 seconds it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'canvas' of null `

Comment: Hm.  It works OK for me with Safari (WebGL enabled) on my Macbook.  Also, you're overloading your use of the variable "screensaver".  You're using it as a query object and as an interval id.

Comment: Slight oversight of the screensaver var. However I am using Firefox where the too much recursion error happens. Are you sure you are attempting to let it go back to the screensaver again?

Comment: @jQueryAngryBird this pertains to the original coders work, and doesn't have to do with the jQuery issue. It is probably because of the `display: none;` on the master element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major issue is that you're binding an event handler inside an interval. During `100ms`, a new event handler will be added to the element.

Another issue is that, you're not resetting the boolean value.

You can try the following:

```js
var screensaver = $('#screensaver'),
    startTime = 5000,
    timeout = null,
    isOff = true;
    function timer() {
      if (!timeout && isOff) { // if no timer exists and screensaver is off, start one
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            screensaver.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                isOff = false; // screensaver active
            });
        }, startTime);
      }
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var interval = setInterval(timer, 1000); // keep checking for timer every 1s
      screensaver.bind('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (timeout) { // if a timer is running, clear it
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = null;
        }
        if (!isOff) { //if the screensaver is active, hide it
            screensaver.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                isOff = true; // screensaver inactive
            });
        }
      });
    });
```

```css
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #1A1A1A;
}
p {
    color:white;
}
#screensaver {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}
#screensaver div{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height:100px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screensaver"><div>Screensaver</div></div>
<br />
<p align="center">Forums and stuff here....
    </p>
```

(*wait for 5 sec to activate screen saver and move mouse inside result window to dismiss it*)

Comment: Thanks TJ. Works great, though when I moved it off of CodePen it fails to run now, with no error. Any idea why it's not starting here: http://lhc.strangled.net/bfx/